# iOS: Best way to position my mapView to show the coordinates at the top left

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have the following code below that positions my mapView where it shows the coordinates in the center. However, I need it to position the mapView where it will show my coordinates at the top left. The code below is what I am currently using. I am using the category called MKMapView+ZoomLevel.h. If you need any more information please let me know.

```
[self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:coordinate zoomLevel:level animated:animated];
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the region with self.mapView.region and find a new coordinate using some simple geometry. Region will give you the center point and the width and height of the view in degrees of latitude and longitude.

From there, you can determine a center coordinate to provide to the map view that will set your original coordinate in the upper left corner.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.mapView.coordinate.latitude +
    self.mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta / 2,
    self.mapView.coordinate.longitude +
    self.mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta / 2)
```